# How do I escape a Ruby string containing interpolation so I can `eval` it later?

Tags: ruby, string, escaping

Suppose `s` is a string that includes some occurrences of interpolation `#{...}` such as:

```
s = " Hello #{Foo.bar(baz) + "}"} \n \" \\ World"
```

What is the simplest way to escape `s` so that this:

```
eval("\"#{s.some_escape_method}\"")
```

or equivalently

```
eval('"' + s.some_escape_method + '"')
```

will expand the interpolations in `s` without affecting any other parts of `s` such as characters `"`, `\n`, etc.?

Comment: Why are you using `eval` for this at all? Wouldn't `String#%` be a much cleaner solution?

Comment: @muistooshort You cannot put code directly in the string with `String#%`.

Comment: Which is often a good thing. Using `%` also means that you don't have brittle local variable references hidden in your strings. Anyway, what does `s` really look like? Does it contain `#{...}` *after* the interpolation has been done or do you want to defer the evaluation of `Foo.bar(bas) + '}'` until later?

Comment: @muistooshort The code inside interpolation is not as complex as to itself contain a string with interpolation so it does not matter, but if it does it should be left unexpanded. Whatever is in the first level of interpolation should be expanded.

Comment: @muistooshort `s` is a JavaScript code, which I want to pre-process with Ruby by expanding whatever is in `#{...}` but retain everything else (outside of interpolation) intact (such as backslashes, double quotes, etc.).

Comment: Then why not simply use single quotes (in any of their forms) for the string and `%` to replace parts of it? If you control the strings then move the method calls out of the strings so that you have some sort of sane interface. There are also dozens of templating systems available, why not use one of those instead of trying to kludge something up with string interpolation and `eval`?

Comment: @muistooshort Most of the template systems use the `<%= ... =>` syntax, which is too complicated to me. I never got used those systems. It might be good for embedding Ruby into HTML or XML (which I never need to do), but it does not look right in JavaScript. Being able to write `#{...}` is much better. I don't understand the first part of your comment. The whole string is written as a file; there is no single/double quote. I just needed to write a string literal using double quotes for this question. As I said, I need to embed Ruby code into the file; `%` will not help.

Answer (score 1):

Surround the possibly-containing-interpolation code string with `%q{}`, which string-izes anything and turns off interpolation.

Let's try an example. Here is some Ruby code in a string:

```rb
z = %q{s = "Hello #{"there, " + name + "!"}"}
# => "s = \"Hello \#{\"there, \" + name + \"!\"}\""
```

If we eval `z`, we will get an interpolated string containing the evaluated value of `s`. Since `s` in this example requires another string called `name` to interpolate correctly, let's define that first:

```
name = "Bob Smith"
eval(z)
# => "Hello there, Bob Smith!"
```

Comment: What do you have `s =` within `%q{...}`? That is redundant.

Comment: @sawa No it isn't. I'm assigning to `z`, not `s`. The effect of _evaluating_ `z` is to assign the interpolated value to `s`.

Comment: Also, your answer is wrong. `eval(%q{"\\ "})` returns `" "`, where I expect to get `"\\ "`.

Comment: @sawa You didn't do what the answer says: surround it with %q{}, not with another level of quotes. `s  = "\\ "; eval(%q{s})`. Read carefully! :)

Comment: I still don't understand why you have `s = `. Without it: `z = %q{"Hello #{"there, " + name + "!"}"}; eval(z)` will give `"Hello there, Bob Smith!"`. It does not make difference. I think you are making the answer more complicated than necessary. If your point was to first assign the string in `%q{...}` to a variable (your `z`) and  then do `eval` instead of directly putting that in `eval`, then I misunderstood it.

Comment: @sawa It does make a difference. Without it, `eval` doesn't change any state -- this proves that it had the result (because you can see that `s` was assigned to, and not merely interpolated). By assigning first to the intermediate value you also avoid parsing problems -- `eval(%q{\\ })` doesn't work but `s = "\\ "; eval(%q{s}) does.

Comment: Why do you need to see `s`? Aren't you only using `z`?

Comment: Are you saying that I need to take these steps separately, and not any two can be combined? 1) `s = the_target_string` 2) `z = %q{s}`, 3) `eval(z)`

Comment: @sawa For the most general case, you can do just (2) and (3). I added (1) to prove, for the purposes of this example, that the `eval` was working as intended (again, because you can see that `s` is assigned after the eval takes place).